# Property lien expiration and removal in North Carolina

Tags: civil-law, real-estate, north-carolina, construction-law

I live in North Carolina and had hired a contractor to work on my house. I'd paid them 50% in advance. They did a terrible job and were a nightmare to work with. I have refused to pay for the remaining work done.

They placed a lien on my house and never filed suit to perfect the lien. It has been over one year since the lien was put in place.

How do I go about removing the lien on my house without a lawyer?

Is there a form that needs to be filed with the NC county clerk's office?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I go about removing the lien on my house without a lawyer?

This is not something that you should attempt without a lawyer. An unrepresented person is 95% likely to screw it up, unless you have done it before with a lawyer's assistance. It will almost surely cost you less in the long run to consult a lawyer than to do it yourself.

> Is there a form that needs to be filed with the NC county clerk's
>   office?

There is no standard form for this kind of issue.